# How do I download MongoDB Server on M1 Mac?

Tags: mongodb, homebrew

I've tried probably 10 different sites looking how to download MongoDB on M1 Mac. And I would like to put this here for anyone who wants to make a step-by-step guide to get MongoDB working on M1 Macs. Feel free to edit this and provide your steps.

For example if I run the following command (`brew install mongodb-community@4.4`), the following error occurs:

```
Error: Cannot install under Rosetta 2 in ARM default prefix (/opt/homebrew)!
To rerun under ARM use:
    arch -arm64 brew install ...
To install under x86_64, install Homebrew into /usr/local.
```

And then I try rerunning in ARM. And it installs successfully. Then I run `mongod` and get `zsh: command not found: mongod`. How is this possible?? It's weird because `mongo` command works just as expected. So mongodb-community is downloaded but I can't access the mongod command.

Does anyone know why? I've tried changing the path but mongod isn't anywhere local...

-- Starting from Rosetta Terminal:

Comment: have you tried to locate the binary and run it directly? maybe is just a PATH issue

Comment: Yes I tried locating the binary but it doesn't exist

Comment: But you were able to find the actual binary file? (called `mongod`).